# withState vs. withStateHandlers

Tags: reactjs, recompose

The docs @ https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withstate says this regarding `withState`

> You'll likely want to use this state updater along with withHandlers()
>   to create specific updater functions.

Then it has a separate function `withStateHandlers()` which seems similar though in a slightly different form.

In terms of practical use and why one would be used instead of the other, how do they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `withStateHandlers()` hasn't appeared until recently version of recompose. I'd recommend that use `withStateHandlers()` instead of combining `withState()` and `withHandlers()` if you can.

The doc under `withState()` probably need update.

Comment: ah, so withState() + withHandlers() is essentially equivalent to withStateHandlers() ?

Comment: For basic usage, yes. For advanced usage, withHandlers let you create stateHandlers by function which withStateHandlers doesn't support and withStateHandlers create one React instance which withSate + withHandlers create two.